# Understanding the equality in triangle inequality.

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors, triangles

The triangle inequality states:

$|z_1 \pm z_2|\le |z_1|+|z_2|$

Equality holds only when the three points are collinear.

It's intuitively obvious for the equality to hold when all vectors are in same direction but I am unable to understand the case with $-$

For example, lets take two vectors $8 \hat{i} , - 3\hat{i}$. They are collinear. According to the triangle inequality:

$|8\hat{i} + (-3\hat{i})|= |8\hat{i|} + |-3\hat{i}|$

$\implies 5 = 11 ,$ which is clearly false.

Please tell me why this is giving the wrong result and how I should interpret the equality case of triangle inequality.

Comment: They point in the opposite direction. You can get the same "contradiction" with $1$ amd $-1$ on the real line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The necessary condition for this equality to work is that the origin $(0,0),z_1,z_2$ must be collinear and *in that order*, i.e., the origin must *not* be in between the line joining $z_1$ and $z_2$.

In your example, the origin is *between* $z_1$ and $z_2$, hence, this - $|8\hat{i} + (-3\hat{i})|= |8\hat{i|} + |-3\hat{i}|$ - fails. However, $|8\hat{i} - (-3\hat{i})|= |8\hat{i|} + |-3\hat{i}|$ works as intended because now, the origin $,-z_2,z_1$ are collinear without the origin being in between them.

I hope this helps!